# joint probability density function for $ X = \sqrt(V) \cdot cos(\Phi) $ and $ Y = \sqrt(V) \cdot sin(\Phi) $

Tags: probability, independence, density-function

Let $U,V$ be two independent  random variables.

$U$ ~ $Uniform(0,2 \pi) $ and $V$ ~ $Exp(\frac{1}{2})$.

We consider  $(X,Y) \in \mathbb{R^2} $ with polar coordinates $R = \sqrt(V)$ and $\phi=U$.

So $X = R \cdot cos(\Phi)$  and $Y = \cdot sin(\Phi)$.

Calculate the joint probability density function for $X,Y$.

My work:

So I know the pdf of $U$ and I know the pdf of $V$.

I can start with $ P( (X,Y) \in A) = P( (\sqrt(V) \cdot cos(\Phi) ,\sqrt(V) \cdot sin(\Phi)) \in A)= P((\sqrt(V),\Phi) \in A')$. So as you can see I will need the joint pdf of $\sqrt(V)$ and $U$. I already compute the pdf of $\sqrt(V)$. But my problem is: are $\sqrt(V)$ and $U$ independent? We know that that $V$ and $U$ are independent.

Comment: What is your working definition of "independent" ?  If it is that the joint density function factors, you could try to work out the joint density of $U$ and $\sqrt V$ and see if it factors, too.

Comment: @kimchilover so independent means: $f_{\sqrt(V)} (w) \cdot f_U (u) = f_{{\sqrt(V)} , U } (w,u) $

Comment: Are you asking me, or telling me?